# Query Sql Server Comments

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to query or extract all comments in procedures, functions, triggers (table and database)?

So pull out stuff like this:

```
/******************************
** I Did Stuff
** 
*******************************/

or 

--I did stuff here --
```

pull out the comments and the object it came from?

Generate something like this:

[image]

Comment: You *could* try to extract the comments from the object definitions.  But comments will often have little meaning without the accompanying tsql.  If you want to start down that path, begin with this:  `SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION, ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be achieved successfully if a standard template is enforced for comments. I have created a script based on this templates

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Proc1
AS
/************************************************************
 * Created by   : Gouri Shankar Aechoor
 * Description  : DEMO EXTRACT DESCRIPTION FROM SP
 * Time         : 8/2/2014 10:06:52 AM
 ************************************************************/
BEGIN
    SELECT   1
END
GO
CREATE TRIGGER utr_Trigger1 ON TEMPTABLE
   AFTER INSERT
AS
/************************************************************
 * Created by   : Gouri Shankar Aechoor
 * Description  : DEMO EXTRACT DESCRIPTION FROM TRIGGER WITH
 *                CONT. ON NEXT LINE
 * Time         : 8/2/2014 10:06:52 AM
 ************************************************************/ 
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
END
GO
```

**This script will extract the Description from these comments**

```
;WITH cte_Comments AS (
                          SELECT     o.name,
                                 OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.[object_id]) AS 
                                 ObjDefinition
                          FROM   sys.objects o
                          WHERE  o.[type] IN ('p', 'tr')
                      )
,cte_RemoveafterBegin AS 
(
    SELECT   cc.name,
             SUBSTRING(
                 cc.ObjDefinition,
                 1,
                 CHARINDEX('BEGIN', cc.ObjDefinition) -1
             )             AS ObjDefinition
             --CHARINDEX('AS',cc.ObjDefinition)
    FROM     cte_Comments     cc
),cte_ExtractComments AS
(
    SELECT   rab.name,
             SUBSTRING(
                 rab.ObjDefinition,
                 CHARINDEX('/*', rab.ObjDefinition) -1,
                 LEN(rab.ObjDefinition)
             )                     AS ObjDefinition
    FROM     cte_RemoveafterBegin     rab
),cte_ExtractDescriptionFrom AS
(
    SELECT   ec.name,
             SUBSTRING(
                 ec.ObjDefinition,
                 CHARINDEX(' * Description', ec.ObjDefinition) + 14,
                 LEN(ec.ObjDefinition)
             )                    AS ObjDefinition
    FROM     cte_ExtractComments     ec
),cte_ExtractDescriptionTo AS
(
    SELECT   edf.name,
             SUBSTRING(
                 edf.ObjDefinition,
                 1,
                 CHARINDEX(' * Time', edf.ObjDefinition) -1
             )                           AS ObjDefinition
    FROM     cte_ExtractDescriptionFrom     edf
)
SELECT   NAME,
     REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                     SUBSTRING(
                         ObjDefinition,
                         CHARINDEX(':', ObjDefinition) + 1,
                         LEN(ObjDefinition)
                     ),
                     CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),
                     ' '
                 ),
                 ' *',
                 ''
             ),
             SPACE(2),
             ''
         ),
         CHAR(9),
         ''
     ) AS ObjDefinition
FROM     cte_ExtractDescriptionTo
```

**Output:**

```
NAME            ObjDefinition
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
usp_Proc1       DEMO EXTRACT DESCRIPTION FROM SP 
utr_Trigger1    DEMO EXTRACT DESCRIPTION FROM TRIGGER WITH CONT. ON NEXT LINE
```